# Why my script is raising TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have written a script to rotate a matrix 90 degrees clockwise. I have figured
out the algorithm but stuck on implementation.

```
def rotate(M):
    #Let M = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    n = len(M)
    temp = None
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            temp = M[i][j]
            M[i][j] = M[j][i]
            M[j][i] = temp
    nby2 = int(n / 2)
    #error loop
    for j in range(0, nby2):
        for i in range(0, n):
            temp = M[i][j]          
            M[i][j] = M[i][n - 1 - j]
            M[i][n - 1 -j] = temp
            #print(M[i][j], M[i][n - 1 - j])

    for i in M:
        print(i)
```

line `temp = M[i][j]` is raising `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`
although print statement returns the element of matrix without the error in error loop and the above loop is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Something you think is a `list` is really an `int`.

Comment: `M[n - 1 -j] = temp` assigns an integer directly to `M`. In the following iterations `M[i]` hits those.

Comment: edit i idiotly put M[n - 1 - j] instead of M[i][n - 1 - j]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the correct soultion:

```
def rotate(M):
    #Let M = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
    n = len(M)
    temp = None
    for i in range(0, n):
        for j in range(i, n):
            temp = M[i][j]
            M[i][j] = M[j][i]
            M[j][i] = temp
    nby2 = int(n / 2)
    #error loop
    print(M, nby2)
    for j in range(0, nby2):
        for i in range(0, n):
            temp = M[i][j]          
            M[i][j] = M[i][n - 1 - j]
            M[i][n - 1 -j] = temp
            #print(M[i][j], M[i][n - 1 - j])

    for i in M:
        print(i)
```

Notice the error in line `M[n - 1 -j][i] = temp`. You forgot to add second index, thus causing list to be replaced with integer.

Comment: I don't agree with you here is the  [code tested online](https://repl.it/KhU0/2) it doesn't give the desired result.

Comment: I just solved the issue OP had, I haven't touched his logic about rotating matrix.

Comment: I thought you intended this answer to be a "complete" answer, in this case you are right.